# Pesquisar elemento de Lista

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca, lista-encadeada

Quero pesquisar um elemento de uma lista através de um nome (vetor de carateres). Recebo o nome (espm) na função e parto para a pesquisa.
O problema é que a função diz-me sempre que "Nao existe medico com essa especialidade" mesmo quando o nome(espm) existe na minha lita (`aux->esp==espm`).

Nota: Já tentei pesquisar por um número (`int` ou `float`) com essa mesma função e deu certo. Mas quando tento pesquisar com uma `string` dá errado. POR QUÊ???

```
void pesquisa_med(char* espm){

MEDICO *aux;
int flag=0;
aux = primeirom->mprox;
while(aux!=NULL){
    if(aux->esp == espm){
        printf("%s %s", aux->mnome, aux->mapelido);
        flag=1;
        aux=NULL;
    }
    else
        aux=aux->mprox;
}
if(!flag)
    printf("Nao existe medico com essa especialidade.");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Não se compara strings assim no C. Como strings são arrays de caracteres, o operador `==` só compara os endereços de memória, e só retoma `true` quando as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo endereço.

O certo é usar a função `strcmp` (ou a sua versão case-insensitive), definida na biblioteca `string.h`. Seu uso é assim:

```
if (strcmp(aux->esp, espm) == 0){ // ...
```